# Download a file built in PHP output buffer from AJAX call

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, download, output

I am trying to build a CSV file in PHP, then call the PHP file from an AJAX call, which will then initiate a download of the CSV file upon success of the AJAX call.  This works fine if I save a physical copy of the .csv on the server, but I would like to use `php://ouput` so I do not have to worry about physical files clogging up the server.  Is it possible to initiate a download from returning `php://output` to AJAX?  Here is my code:

HTML/jquery:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
             $("#download").live("click", function() {
                var request = $.ajax({
                    dataType: 'html',
                    url: 'php.php',
                    success: function(response) {
                        alert('Finished');
                    }
                })
            })
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1 id="download">DOWNLOAD</h1>
    </body>
</html>
```

PHP:

```
<?php 
    header('Content-type: application/vnd.ms-excel');
    header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename="test.csv"');
    $f = fopen('php://output', 'w');
    fwrite($f,'this,is,a,test');
    fclose($f);
    readfile('php://output');
    return;
?>
```

I am not sure how to get this to return a File Save dialog from my AJAX call.

This has to be simple, but I can't seem to find any examples that combines these two issues.

Comment: ajax isn't for file downloads. simply set the new iframe's src to be the download url and let it loose.

Comment: I would just open the page in a new window using `window.open()` since there isn't any output it should just initiate the download.

Comment: You seem to be a little confused as to what a URL is.  A URL is an address of a resource on the internet.  The URL could point to a file, or a PHP script, or any of a number of different things.  Additionally, you're sending the wrong content-type.  It should be text/csv

Comment: No need to open a new page if you have a hidden iframe that points to the php download address (as Marc wrote).

Comment: Not sure you are able to open save dialog from JavaScript ... should be potected!

Comment: I should have really left out the `download` portion, that was used when I was returning a URL of the file when I was creating an actual file server-side.  So, I think what you are saying is I really can't do anything from within the AJAX/JavaScript code to get the download?  I need to somehow modify the php.php code to send me the file?

Comment: Interesting way to connect a file handler to the output stream! Didn't know it. Thanks.

Comment: Ok, I have restated my question.  The AJAX call returns the correct headers and body, but it doesn't do anything with them.  How do I get the response of the PHP to open the save file dialog?

Comment: I should also mention I would like to keep it in the AJAX call because I am grabbing data from a SQL call, and would like to have a "Processing..." indication while its grabbing the data.  I see that I can do it by just calling `window.open()` but I would like some sort of indication that it is doing something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following works, but is highly inneficient as it calls the php.php file twice.  Does anybody have any better ideas?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
             $("#download").live("click", function() {
                var request = $.ajax({
                    dataType: 'html',
                    url: 'php.php',
                    success: function(response) {
                        window.open('php.php');
                    }
                })
            })
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1 id="download">DOWNLOAD</h1>
    </body>
</html>
```

Is there anyway to cache 'php.php' for just this instance so that it loads instantly under `window.open('php.php')`, but will reload contents when I click `download` next?

Why does `window.open(response)` not work the same?

Answer (score 3):

You can do this by creating and sending form via jquery (page not reloaded):

```
$(document).on('click', '#download', function () {
    var form = $(document.createElement('form'));
    form.attr('action', 'php.php');
    form.attr('method', 'GET');
    form.appendTo(document.body);
    form.submit();
    form.remove();
});
```

Also you can pass post parameters if need:

```
$(document).on('click', '#download', function () {
    var form = $(document.createElement('form'));
    form.attr('action', 'php.php');
    form.attr('method', 'POST');
    var input = $('<input>').attr('type', 'hidden').attr('name', 'x').val('x value');
    form.append(input);
    form.appendTo(document.body);
    form.submit();
    form.remove();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

look this：

```php
if (!headers_sent()) {
    // seconds, minutes, hours, days
    $expires = 60*60*24*14;
    header('Pragma: public');
    header('Cache-Control: maxage=' . $expires);
    header('Expires: ' . gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s', time() + $expires) . ' GMT');
}
```

Note: this will not work with POST requests, just GET.

Answer (score -2):

To allow for a file download, you can simply call the below code (say on a button's onclick):

```
window.open(<file-url>);
```

Hope this helps.